# FB api for Unity3d. Select all friends

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-friends

I use FB api for selecting friends for my app with following code ([doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.AppRequest))

```
FB.AppRequest(
        message,
        null,
        new List<object> (){ "app_users" },
        null,
        null,
        jsonData,
        null,
        RequestResult
    );
```

But in window with selecting friends is no button `Select All`. Can I add it to native window? Or I have to write my own window with selecting?

Comment: why would you want to select all friends? what for exactly? sounds spammy, i don´t think it´s possible.

Comment: @luschn for send gift to my friends, that is one example

Comment: well...that sounds even more spammy...you should not mass-send stuff. just let the user select the friends he wants to send a gift to.

Comment: @luschn May be you right. But that is my task and I can't decide about better solution

Comment: this may be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574635/fb-apprequests-how-many-friends-can-i-invite-at-a-time